# scala parameterized type on foldLeft

Tags: scala, types, parameterized, foldleft

given the following signature for a parameterized method

```
def double[A <: Byte](in:List[A]): List[A] = {
  //double the values of the list using foldLeft
  //for ex. something like:
  in.foldLeft(List[A]())((r,c) => (2*c) :: r).reverse
  //but it doesn't work! so.. 
}
```

i was trying to get the following before tackling parameterized typed foldLeft

```
def plainDouble[Int](in:List[Int]): List[Int] = {
  in.foldLeft(List[Int]())((r:List[Int], c:Int) => {
   var k = 2*c
   println("r is ["+r+"], c is ["+c+"]")
   //want to prepend to list r
   // k :: r 
   r
})
}
```

however, this results in the following error:

```
$scala fold_ex.scala
error: overloaded method value * with alternatives:
(x: Double)Double <and>
(x: Float)Float <and>
(x: Long)Long <and>
(x: scala.Int)scala.Int <and>
(x: Char)scala.Int <and>
(x: Short)scala.Int <and>
(x: Byte)scala.Int
cannot be applied to (Int(in method plainDouble))
val k = 2*c
         ^
one error found
```

if i changed the signature of the def to the following:

```
def plainDouble(in:List[Int]): List[Int] = { ...}
```

works and the output for :

```
val in = List(1,2,3,4,5)
println("in "+ in + " plainDouble ["+plainDouble(in)+"]")
```

is

```
in List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5) plainDouble [List(2, 4, 6, 8, 10)]
```

apologies if i am missing something very obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DNA is correct in that `plainDouble[Int]` declares a type parameter named `Int`, that has nothing to do with the actual type. So your attempt to make it non-generic is actually still generic, but in a way that is not quickly apparent.

But what about the original problem?

```
scala> def double[A <: Byte](in: List[A]): List[A] = in.foldLeft(List.empty[A])((r,c) => (2*c) :: r)
<console>:15: error: type mismatch;
 found   : x$1.type (with underlying type Int)
 required: A
       def double[A <: Byte](in: List[A]): List[A] = in.foldLeft(List.empty[A])((r,c) => (2*c) :: r).reverse
                                                                                               ^
```

The problem here is that `2 * c` is an `Int`, and not an `A`. The `*(byte: Byte)` method on `Int` returns another `Int`. Hence the message `(with underlying type Int)`. Notice that if you cast to `A`, it compiles:

```
def double[A <: Byte](in: List[A]): List[A] =
    in.foldLeft(List.empty[A])((r,c) => (2*c).toByte.asInstanceOf[A] :: r).reverse
```

Notice how I also had to call `toByte` before casting to `A`. This isn't exactly a shining example of generics at work, but the point is that incompatible return types are causing the error.

Also notice how it doesn't occur if you remove `2 *`:

```
def double[A <: Byte](in: List[A]): List[A] =
    in.foldLeft(List.empty[A])((r,c) => c :: r).reverse
```

---

Edit:

You might consider using the `Numeric` trait for generics like this.

```
import scala.math.Numeric.Implicits._

def double[A: Numeric](in: List[A])(implicit i2a: Int => A): List[A] =
    in.map(_ * 2)
```

This relies on an implicit `Numeric[A]` being available for your numeric type (which there are in the `scala.math.Numeric` object, for pretty much any numeric type you will want).  It also relies on an implicit conversion being available from `Int` to `A`, so that we can write `a * 2`. We can drop this constraint by using `+` instead:

```
def double[A: Numeric](in: List[A]): List[A] = in.map(a => a + a)
```

Comment: thank you "DNA" and @m-z  however, `def doubleBound[A <: Byte](in: List[A]): List[A] =
    in.foldLeft(List.empty[A])((r,c) => (2*c).toByte.asInstanceOf[A] :: r).reverse

   val in = List(1,2,3,4,5)
   println("in "+ in + " doubleBound ["+doubleBound(in)+"]")`  still complains with `error: inferred type arguments [Int] do not conform to method doubleBound's type parameter bounds [A <: Byte]`

Comment: @cogitate An `Int` is not `Byte`. `A` cannot represent an `Int`, if `A` is bounded above by `Byte`.

Comment: Try using an actual list of `Byte`s:  `List(1, 2, 3). map(_.toByte)`

Comment: agree!! so what should a generic double that takes a list of numbers look like?

Comment: @cogitate See my edit. The issue is really that the numeric types in scala do not extend a common type other than `AnyVal`. However, there is the `Numeric` type class, which you may be interested in.

Comment: @m-v thank you for spending so much time on this. grateful. i will mark your answer as "correct". i just drank too much kool-aid that in scala i can really write generic interfaces and handle the types. foldLeft is what i am learning slowly and haven't yet understood how to use implicits.thank you.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is a kind of name shadowing:

```
def plainDouble[Int](in:List[Int]): List[Int] = {
                ^^^
      // this is a type parameter called "Int"
```

You are declaring a type variable called `Int`, whilst also trying to use the concrete type `Int`, and this causes the confusion. If you remove the type variable (since it's not actually used) or rename it to `I`, for example, then the code compiles.

Comment: yes, as i too found. however, how would you make  the parameterized type work?